# One click unsubscribe and List-Unsubscribe - name of mailing list?

Tags: email, email-spam

Gmail and Yahoo are strengthening the requirement to use `List-Unsubscribe` and `List-Unsubscribe-Post` header fields for one-click unsubcribe.

When you have these headers, Gmail will show a little `Unsubscribe` link next to the sender.  When you click on this, Gmail will show a prompt like this:

[image]

The name it shows here appears to be the name from the `From:` header field.  But this can be misleading, because it suggests that what will happen is that you will unsubscribe from mails from a specific sender, whereas what will happen is that you leave an entire mailing list (or site).

Is there any way to control the list name which is shown here, so that it can be made more appropriate?